# How to groupy by Column1 and multiply Column2 with Count(*)?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, group-by

this is what i'm trying to achieve:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) * dd.Material_Quantity as [Count], tabSparePart.SparePartName
FROM         tabDataDetail AS dd INNER JOIN
                      tabSparePart ON dd.fiSparePart = tabSparePart.idSparePart
WHERE    dd.Reused_Indicator = 1
GROUP BY tabSparePart.SparePartName
ORDER BY Count DESC, tabSparePart.SparePartName
```

Count all sparepart occurences and multiply them with their corresponding `Material_Quantity` value.
But i get following error:

> 8118: Column 'tabDataDetail.Material_Quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function and there is no GROUP BY
>   clause.

How can i multiply both values meaningfully? Would a simple  `SUM` or `AVG` give the correct result? For example: `COUNT(*) * AVG(dd.Material_Quantity) as [Count]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the sum of quantities, you could use `sum`:

```
SUM(dd.Material_Quantity)
```

Comment: Hmm, you mean i don't need to select count(*) at all because i anyway want to get Material_Quantity. That makes sense. Thank you. `Sum` will only sum the rows that match the  `Where`-condition and `Group-By`?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Yeah, this only sums rows that match `where`, and the `sum` is only for rows in the group.

Comment: I've accepted your answer although i have the problem that many rows have a linked sparepart but material_quantity is null or 0. I think i will change them to 1. Edit: Solved: I've forgotten to add another condition in my where clause.